# NODEJS : chat with a CSS style sheet implementation

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to create an interactive chat with nodejs. I have everything but i want to integrate a theme system.
I have my themes and a menu that allows you to change, but I do not know how to make a theme applies at all the users.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.csszengarden.com/

Comment: Thanks you but I want that all users can change the css style sheet and instantly applies to everyone. I can do that with socket.io but i don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you are looking for:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs--net-31708